# javascript to disable a button

Tags: javascript, button

I want a click action to disable a button on the fifth click, but I can't get the  to work inside the 
Here's the javascript...

```
var currentTurn = 1;

function taketurn(){
  currentTurn++;
  document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = currentTurn;
  threeturns(currentTurn);
}
function threeturns(now) {
  if(now > 3){
    document.getElementById("livedead").innerHTML = "disabled";
  }
}
```

Then html

```
<div class="container">
<h1>turn <span id="turn">1</span></h1>
    <button onclick="taketurn()" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" <span id="livedead"></span> />  next</button>
    <button onclick="taketurn()" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" disabled>  next</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `livedead` is the id the `<span>` in your HTML, so `document.getElementById("livedead")` gets the `span`, not the `button`. You need to select the button. After that, you need to use [`createattribute`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createattribute.asp) to add the `disabled` attribute. `innerHTML` replaces all the inner HTML, so literally would just show the text "disabled"

Comment: @futureprogress there is an error in the syntax of your HTML, inside your first `button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to change a little with your code. Some corrections need to be made to your HTML so that the `livedead` span is not defined inside the opening `<button>` tag.

Also, disabling a button with javascript is done by setting the `disabled` field on that buttons `Node` object (ie not by setting innerHTML to disabled).

I would suggest a few changes to your code - the key one being to use the `MouseEvent` object.

In your case, this would simplify disabling the button that your user is clicking. To illustrate the use of the `MouseEvent` object, consider this code:

```js
var currentTurn = 1;

// add a parameter to function to give us access to the event
// for this click interaction
function taketurn(event){
 
  // if click count is 5 or more, then disable this button
  if(currentTurn >= 5) {
  
    // we access the button via the event parameter that we 
    // passed in. The currentTarget represents the button, so
    // we can set disabled on the button to disable it.
    event.currentTarget.disabled = 'disabled'
  }
   
  currentTurn ++;
  
  document.getElementById("turn").innerHTML = currentTurn;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<h1>turn <span id="turn">1</span></h1>
    <!-- pass event defined for the click interaction, to taketurn() -->
    <button onclick="taketurn(event)" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" id="livedead">  next</button>
    <button onclick="taketurn()" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" disabled>  next</button>
</div>
```